# Is "mi estas irinta vespermanĝi" correct?

Tags: verbs, grammar

Is "mi estas irinta vespermanĝi" correct, or is there a better way of forming the "vespermanĝi" part?

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what you're trying to ask. It's hard to know if it's correct if we don't know what you're trying to say. I've posted an answer below. If it doesn't answer the question you were trying to ask, please leave a comment.

Comment: This question might have some useful information: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/can-i-use-iri-with-other-verbs

Answer (score 7):

This is a grammatical sentence in Esperanto, but the *estas -inta* wording is a little heavy. It could probably be replaced with *iris* depending on what you're trying to say.

Comment: Yes, „Mi iris vespermanĝi”. The other sentence is grammatically correct, but almost never used.

Answer (score 4):

"Mi estas irinta vespermanĝi" signifas "I have gone to eat dinner". Ĝi estas iomete teda, ĉu ne? Tomaso Alexander pravas, ke vi povas anstataŭigi "estas irinta" kun simple "iris".

Sed mi volas respondi al via alia demandparto. Oni povas diri ion kiel ĉi tio:

> Vidante la naĝejon, li ekvolis iri naĝi. [Looking at the pool made
>   him want to go swimming.]

Do, eĉ kvankam tio eble ŝajnas iomete stranga, ne zorgu. Vi pravas.

Comment: "Vidante" ne povas esti subjekto. Devas esti "vidi la naĝejon..."

Comment: Aŭ "vidante la naĝejon, li ekvolis iri naĝi".

Comment: Ah, tio sonas pli natura. Dankon.

Comment: Cxu vere "voli iri nagxi"? Laux mi gxi devus esti nur "voli nagxi" cxar se iu vidas nagxejon ne vere necesas iri ien ajn por nagxi. "Go swimming" tre ofte estas nur "nagxi" en Esperanto.